# Chart control grayed out in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, charts

Hi i have searched the web with several people complaining about the same trouble .Some found the solution , some did not.

I have a Winform application created in C# using Visual Studio.
I have two computers : One has Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop and another is Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and both have the same trouble.

Under my "Data" tab i see no option that says "Chart".

Here is what i tried :

1. right clicked "Data" and clicked "Show all items". I get "Chart" but that is grayed out.
2. I tried resetting the toolbox , but the result is same.
3. I tried right clicking and chose " Choose items" . There i see my "Chart" control , both for web and winforms and both are checked.

It also shows the following description :

Language : Invariant Language (Invariant Country)
Version  : 4.0.0.0

Please help .

Change : I downloaded the DataVisualization.dll and tried adding reference manually. I am now able to add the reference with "using" keyword. 
I also tried to drag the dll in the toolbox and it dows show me the new chart control but that is still grayed out.

Comment: Can you manuall add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization`and the using clause `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;` and then create a Chart in code?

Comment: I tried but i am not able to find the reference

Comment: only Windows.Forms is available , I don't get an option to reference DataVisualization

Comment: So ` System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll` is missing on your machine(s)? Sounds like an incomplete installation. Did you opt out on database stuff? (Not sure if that's even possible)

Comment: @TaW : I did downloaded the dll but it is still grayed out

Comment: What about `System.Data.dll`? May a re-install (to add or change features, not uninstalling) is necessary.

Comment: @TaW : i tried to compile my program now and got an error :   "The primary reference "system.windows.forms.datavisualization" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework."

Answer (score 0):

Well am not sure what made it work . But after downloading the dll and adding a manual reference, i had to restart Visual Studio. I still have the item grayed out and i am not able to drag the control in my application . But strangely now when i right click and choose to copy the control and go in my WinForm applicatin and paste it . It does show up the control there.

Comment: instead of downloading a single DLL I recommend doing a repair install. .NET is rather picky with the assemblies' versioning.

Comment: Yeah that's what i screwed up with now